# create multidientional array in foreach loop with parent array values as key

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having an array as follows from which i m creating new array with post value as key in new array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Max right
            [uid] => 148
            [post] => Sales
            [post_id] => 870
            [score] => 2.3333
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Max right
            [uid] => 148
            [post] => Dev
            [skill_id] => 881
            [score] => 3.5
        )

    [10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Ron Deck
            [uid] => 118
            [post] => Sales
            [skill_id] => 870
            [score] => 2
        )

    [11] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Ron Deck
            [uid] => 118
            [post] => Dev
            [skill_id] => 881
            [score] => 4
        )

    [20] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => MIndy Sane
            [uid] => 16
            [post] => Sales
            [post_id] => 870
            [score] => 3
        )

    [21] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => MIndy Sane
            [uid] => 16
            [post] => Dev
            [post_id] => 881
            [score] => 5
        )

)
```

I tried to group by their uid as follows to get required output

```
$records = [];
        foreach ($data as $out_data)
        {
            $records[$out_data->uid][] = $out_data->score ;
            $records[$out_data->uid][] = $out_data->name ;
            $records[$out_data->uid][] = $out_data->post_id ;
            $records[$out_data->uid][] = $out_data->post ;
        }
```

and getting output as follows not sure about right approach. basically in main array i have values out of which i have to use as key but not able to find way

```
Array
(
    [148] => Array
        (
            [0] => Max right
            [1] => 2.3333
            [2] => 870
            [3] => Sales
            [4] => Max right
            [5] => 3.5
            [6] => 881
            [7] => Dev
        )
    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ron Deck
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 870
            [3] => Sales
            [4] => Ron Deck
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 881
            [7] => Dev
        )
    [121] => Array
        (
            [0] => MIndy Sane
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 870
            [3] => Sales
            [4] => Ron Deck
            [5] => 5
            [6] => 881
            [7] => Dev
        )
```

My expected output is as follows

```
$records = array(
            array('name'=> 'Max right', 'Sales' =>2.3333, 'Dev'=>3.5),
            array('name'=> 'Ron Deck', 'Sales' =>2, 'Dev'=>4),
            array('name'=> 'MIndy Sane', 'Sales' =>3, 'Dev'=>5),
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your loop:

```
$records = []
foreach ($data as $out_data) {
    if (empty($records[$out_data->uid])) {
        $records[$out_data->uid] = [
            'name' => $out_data->name;
        ];
    }

    $records[$out_data->uid][$out_data->post] = $out_data->score;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it.  Name the keys using `$out_data->post`.  Obviously this is assuming that it is not repeated for each person:

```
foreach ($data as $out_data)
{
    $records[$out_data->uid]['name'] = $out_data->name;
    $records[$out_data->uid][$out_data->post] = $out_data->score;
}
```

Then re-index if you want (not needed):

```
$records = array_values($records);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` with `array_key_exists`

```
$res = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
  if(array_key_exists($val['uid'], $res)){
    $res[$val['uid']][$val['post']] =  $val['score'];
  }else{
    $res[$val['uid']] = [
                'name'       => $val['name'],
                $val['post'] => $val['score']
    ];
  }
}
```

[Live example](https://3v4l.org/l6rfC)